# Capture indefinite amount of numbers with Regex?

Tags: regex, infinite-sequence

I want to get captures using regex on a string that could contain an indefinite amount of numbers. My intuition lead me to do `"/\.getnumbers (\d+)+\s*/"`but that only matched the first number following the `.getnumbers` command. How do I write a regex statement that will capture one or more numbers after the command separated by a simple space. For example: `.getnumbers 5 4 3 2 1` would match `(5) (4) (3) (2) (1)`, though the regex isn't specifically written to match 5 numbers, it could match any amount of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't do it without postprocessing, since most regex engines don't allow an indefinite number of groups. Fortunately the postprocessing consists only of splitting by spaces.

```
/\.getnumbers (\d+(?: \d+)*)/
```

Comment: I agree that trying to have separate groups for each doesn’t make much sense, but I was unaware that “most regex engines don’t allow an indefinite number of groups.” I know that both Perl and PCRE are limited only by available virtual memory. What commonly used languages are more restrictive than that? (Thanks.)

Comment: @tchrist: They allow you to have an arbitrarily large, definite number of groups. But you still need one pair of `()` per group.

Comment: Ah, I see.  People are always wanting `/(?:\b(\d+)\b\s*)+/` to populate more than just the `$1` which that pattern accounts for. The issue returns when they match `"12 345 523" =~ /(?:\b(?<N>\d+)\b\s*)+/` and now figure that `@{ $-{N} }` holds a list of all the matches.

Answer (score 2):

```
/\.getnumbers (\d+(?:\s+\d+)*)/
```

Note that you'll get all of the numbers as a single capture group. eg: "5 4 3 2 1"